# Specifying a terminal node in a Bayesian Network

Tags: r, bayesian, bayesian-network, graphical-model, bnlearn

I am writing R script using bnlearn package for learning a DAG from a dataset. Is it possible to define a terminal node beforehand? ie I want a node Y to be the final one in the graph, which will not affect any other node.

Comment: you can use the blacklist/whitelist argument to disallow edges in the net e.g. to disallow any edge from your terminal (leaf) node to any of the others (see https://www.bnlearn.com/examples/whitelist/). However, this could still learn a graph where there is no edge towards your terminal node unless you specifically added these to the whitelist.